# Project name saves to database instead of string when using Create

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a bit of a problem with my MVC website, with the database saving specifically. So essentially, I have created a page where you can add a new Category to the database. But when it uses the WCF Web service's function, it seems to save the Solution name rather than the string that was input in the Create form.

The service function:

```
public string addCategory(string Name)
    {
        Database1Entities1 tbl = new Database1Entities1();
        Category newCtg = new Category() {
            Namn = Name,
        };
        tbl.Category.Add(newCtg);
        try
        {
            tbl.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            Exception raise = dbEx;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    // raise a new exception nesting
                    // the current instance as InnerException
                    raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                }
            }
            throw raise;
        }
        string msg = "Done";
        return msg;
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Category/
    localhost.Service1 srvc = new localhost.Service1();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Category newCtg)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            srvc.addCategory(newCtg.ToString());
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And the cshtml file:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Category</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Namn, new { @class = "control-label      col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Namn)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Namn)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot of DB:

[image: database structure]

Comment: What data layer are you using? Entity Framework? Please [edit] your question with the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the project name but the class name.

Default implementation of ToString() on an object returns the class name.

Instead of

```
srvc.addCategory(newCtg.ToString());
```

use

```
srvc.addCategory(newCtg.Namn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
srvc.addCategory(newCtg.ToString());
To
srvc.addCategory(newCtg.Namn);

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is `srvc.addCategory(newCtg.ToString());`.  Unless you have a specific overridden `ToString()` function for the `Category` object, that is simply going to return the name of the reference type you feed into it.  The view suggests that this should instead be `srvc.addCategory(newCtg.Namn)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `Create` Action method of CategoryController, extactly this line:

```
srvc.addCategory(newCtg.ToString());
```

`newCtg` is a Category entity type. So `ToString()` method of `newCtg` returns the entity type. That´s why entity type is saved. To save category name you need to pass the `Name` property of your model to the service:

```
srvc.addCategory(newCtg.Namn);
```